# Aggregate query using percentage data

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, aggregation

i have a query that calculates the production efficiency of oil for a number of companies and their assets.. The query at the moment is on an asset level and i need to re-write it to aggregate to a company level..

Here is the code:

```
SELECT qb1.CompanyName, qb1.AssetName, qb1.Year,
       (((qb1.DefaultOil*1000000)/qb2.MPPOil)*100) AS PEOIL
FROM PE_Field_OIL_GAS AS qb1 
INNER JOIN PE_Field_MPPOilRevised AS qb2 
ON qb1.Assetname=qb2.AssetName;
```

It is based on the calculation:

**((OIL × 1000000) ÷ MPP Oil revised) × 100**

Where MMPOil is a calculated column in another field.

An example of how the aggregated calculation works is below:

**(((assetA OIL × 1000000) + (assetA OIL × 1000000)) 
÷ (assetA MPP Oil revised + assetB MPP Oil revised)) 
× 100**

Please note that this query outputs a **percentage** so its not just a case of summing all asset level data! Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might sum both sides and then calculate percentage, grouping by company and year. If you do not need year, remove it both from select list and group by list.

```
SELECT qb1.CompanyName, qb1.Year,
       (((sum(qb1.DefaultOil)*1000000)/sum(qb2.MPPOil))*100) AS PEOIL
FROM PE_Field_OIL_GAS AS qb1 
INNER JOIN PE_Field_MPPOilRevised AS qb2 
ON qb1.Assetname=qb2.AssetName
GROUP BY qb1.CompanyName, qb1.Year;
```

Comment: Sorry i have another question, for the same calculation structure but with different variables i get an 'Overflow' error, im assuming its because the values are too long.. Do you have any idea how i could round data up to the nearest whole number? (I could add this function to the asset calculation in my question)

Comment: @Magda There is [round function](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/numeric/round.php) in MS Access but I don't think it will help. `Overflow` probably comes from crossing the variable type value borderline. If this is the case you might use wider [numeric variable](http://www.functionx.com/access/Lesson20.htm) - convert `qb1.DefaultOil` and `qb2.MPPOil` to double using [CDbl](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/datatype/cdbl.php).

Comment: I tried converting them both to doubles but the error remained, i tried converting them both to whole numbers with no decimal places but the problem still remains :S

Comment: @Magda What is exact error message? Do you get it when running query alone or from form/report? What datatypes are DefaultOil and MPPOil? Ah, if range is widely different division can produce this problem - does it work if you divide first and then multiply by hundred million?

Comment: The exact error message is Overflow

I get it when running the query alone. 

The query you submitted as an answer with DefaultOil and MPPOil works, the issue im having is with a similar calculation using WellworkOil and MPPOil..

The code


SELECT qb1.CompanyName, qb1.Year, ((sum(qb1.ExportOIL)*1000000)/sum(qb2.MPPOil))*100 AS ExportOIL
FROM PE_Field_ExportOIL AS qb1 INNER JOIN PE_Field_MPPOilRevised AS qb2 ON qb1.Assetname=qb2.AssetName
GROUP BY qb1.CompanyName, qb1.Year;

ExportOil has data values between 0-51 (its a percentage)
MPPOil has values between 0-104066918

Comment: @Magda I suppose there is a value close to zero in sum(MPPOil) producing division overflow. Could you check smallest value in this sum and remove this company from query to test this hypothesis?

Comment: Sorry, i have managed to get it to work now. One of the values in the WellworkOil query dataset was a '#Num!' after removing it the query was able to execute

Comment: @Magda Glad it turned out well.